# Trying to pass a nested list with JSON to JS with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-3.x, flask

The problem is I'm passing my argument to the Javascript like this: [link.](https://codeshare.io/pq4bx4)

The variable "chatlist" is the problem. The value of that variable is

```
[[{"user": "lol"}, {"msg": "lol has created this chat."}], [{"user": "lol"}, {"msg": "lol"}]]
```

But when I try to access that variable through this code: [link](https://codeshare.io/K8R3dz), it ends up looking like

```
[[{&#34;user&#34;: &#34;lol&#34;}, {&#34;msg&#34;: &#34;lol has created this chat.&#34;}], [{&#34;user&#34;: &#34;lol&#34;}, {&#34;msg&#34;: &#34;lol&#34;}]]
```

What I'm expecting is in both my Python code and my Javascript, I get

```
[[{"user": "lol"}, {"msg": "lol has created this chat."}], [{"user": "lol"}, {"msg": "lol"}]]
```

as the value of the variable labelled "chatList". This value also needs to be "parsable" (not sure if that's the right word). I need to be able to access all elements of the list and all keys and values of each dictionary in each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the list as is to `render_template`.

```py
return render_template("chat.html", chatlist=chatInfo, pin=pin)
```

In the template you can use the jinja filter [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson).

```js
var chatList = {{ chatlist | tojson }};
console.log(chatList);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the double quotes are getting HTML escaped.

I would solve this by using [Javascript's decodeURI() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp).